# How to get the Menu with list of choices using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, menuitem

i'm trying to get the Menu with different style in jquery mobile with list of choices in the page footer.Like as shown below.

[image]

**Updated:**

My code is here 
  but in keep the menu option in the header but when i keep this footer it show the options in menu below.

Comment: "[I'm] trying to get the Menu" are you? What have you tried? What's your code? Please *read your question* and then work out in what possible way we could offer any answer to this 'question'. What, for example, *is* the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mcxbP/ sorry code is here.

Comment: What is your requirement

Comment: how to get the menu design like in the above image

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Comment: my code is working fine. can you give me any suggestions to design the menu like above picture.